# Hibernated Windows 8 does not boot (Dell Inspiron 15)

Tags: windows-8, boot, linux-mint, hibernate, hybrid-sleep

I recently installed Linux Mint 15 along with my Windows 8 (probably 8.1, I cannot remember if I updated it or not). I remember some time ago I restarted Linux and as the DELL logo appeared I pressed F12 to enter the boot options and I selected Windows UEFI boot. Windows seemed to load but then the UI never showed up. I have never been able to access Windows since that time. I also tried to let it load Windows for hours, it didn't work. Sometimes the bleeping lights on the side of the machine show some disc activity (also the noises make me think it is "thinking"), but the black screen stays there and nothing changes. I am sure Windows is in hibernate mode or sleep mode, and I cannot mount it from Linux.

Can you help me?

Thank you!